# logging to /dev/xconsole does not work properly

Tags: logs, pipe, syslog, rsyslog

I am using `rsyslog`, and I want to send logs to `/dev/xconsole`.

I have following relevant line in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
*.*;cron.!=info;mail.!=info   |/dev/xconsole
```

This works only partially. It looks as if `/dev/xconsole` can only store cca 64kB. Once the buffer is full, new logs are lost

I have done following test:

```
1) add to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`
*.*;cron.!=info;mail.!=info    /tmp/aaa

2) reboot

3) cat /dev/xconsole > /tmp/bbb

4) diff /tmp/aaa /tmp/bbb
```

Now, aaa and bbb should be the same. But they are not. aaa contains complete logs, while bbb is missing 229 last lines

How can I fix this problem?
Is the size of `/dev/xconsole` indeed limited ?
Can I increase the size?

Comment: Something is supposed to read from `/dev/xconsole` from the moment you start logging. You need to start that `cat /dev/xconsole` before you start rsyslogd.

Comment: @Gilles - I need the whole log output. I cannot discard it. Is it possible to increase the size of `/dev/xconsole` to 128 KB ?

Comment: @Martin Vegter: The solution (of a real problem) is obvious: **discard /dev/xconsole and log directly to file(s).** Why do you seek adventures here?

Comment: @IncnisMrsi. If you open a fifo with O_WRONLY, the open blocks (or fails (with ENXIO on Linux) for a non-blocking open) and the pipe is not instantiated until something opens in RDONLY or RDWR. On Linux, if you open with O_RDWR, the pipe is instantiated and you can start writing data to it. (which can be read by yourself (on that same fd where reading reads from the other end of the pipe) or other processes opening the fifo in RDONLY or RDWR mode).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: thanks for pointing out, which namely system call is blocked when nobody reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `/dev/xconsole` has no *size* since it’s a named pipe a.k.a. [fifo](/questions/tagged/fifo). But the Linux kernel supplies each such object, when in use, with a buffer, 64 KiB (in Linux 3.x) or 4 KiB (in Linux 2.x). Not in the filesystem, only in memory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624071/pipe-buffer-size-is-4k-or-64k and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229544/80483 for more information.

If the application (xconsole) doesn’t read its data timely, then the buffer becomes full; syslog can’t write there and, avoiding to be blocked, drops messages.